# Swift: When do you need to import classes?

Tags: swift

In Swift if I create a class it seems you don't need to import it to access it from another class.  But for "framework" classes we're using such as SwiftyJSON and Alamofire we do have to import them.  When do you need to import classes in Swift?

Note the framework classes I'm referring to are configured via Cocoapods and are in a separate project within the same workspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Never.

You never need to import *classes*.  You need to import *modules*.  Any time you want to use anything in one module which comes from another module, you must import that module.

---

If you want to import your own custom modules, you first need a framework.

Add a framework to your project.

[image]

I named mine `MyFramework` (and also created a test target):

[image]

[image]

---

Now, make sure that your framework is linked to your main target (or whatever target you want to use it from):

[image]

If it's not here, add it with the plus button.

[image]

---

Now, go import it:

[image]

And note that from *this* target, you'll only able to use things from `MyFramework` if they're marked `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to import modules, where all of the classes are stored. For example, using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON in networking class you created would look something like this:

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class NetworkCall {

....
}
```

A basic rule of thumb is, if you install a framework via Cocoapods, then you would need to import that module before using it in your personal CoccaTouchClass file or SwiftFile.